# Async WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

To make this easier to understand: We are using a database that does not have connection pooling built in. We are implementing our own connection pooler.

Ok so the title probably did not give the best description. Let me first Describe what I am trying to do. We have a WCF Service (hosted in a windows service) that needs to be able to take/process multiple requests at once. The WCF service will take the request and try to talk to (say) 10 available database connections. These database connections are all tracked by the WCF service and when processing are set to busy. If a request comes in and the WCF tries to talk to one of the 10 database connections and all of them are set to busy we would like the WCF service to wait for and return the response when it becomes available.

We have tried a few different things. For example we could have while loop (yuck)

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
ExecuteProgram(string clientId, string program, string[] args)
{
    string requestId = DbManager.RegisterRequest(clientId, program, args);
    string response = null;
    while(response == null)
    {
        response = DbManager.GetResponseForRequestId(requestId);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Basically the DbManager would track requests and responses. Each request would call the DbManager which would assign a request id. When a database connection is available it would assign (say) Responses[requestId] = [the database reponse]. The request would constantly ask the DbManager if it had a response and when it did the request could return it.

This has problems all over the place. We could possibly have multiple threads stuck in while loops for who knows how long. That would be terrible for performance and CPU usage. (To say the least)

We have also looked into trying this with events / listeners. I don't know how this would be accomplished so the code below is more of how we envisioned it working.

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
ExecuteProgram(string clientId, string program, string[] args)
{
    // register an event
    // listen for that event
    // when that event is called return its value
}
```

We have also looked into the DbManager having a queue or using things like Pulse/Monitor.Wait (which we are unfamiliar with).

So, the question is: How can we have an async WCF Operation that returns when it is able to?

Comment: Guard your connection pool with a Semaphore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF supports the async/await keywords in .net 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx.  You would need to do a bit of refactoring to make your ExecuteProgram async and make your DbManager request operation awaitable.

If you need your DbManager to manage the completion of these tasks as results become available for given clientIds, you can map each clientId to a `TaskCompletionSource`.  The `TaskCompletionSource` can be used to create a `Task` and the DbManager can use the `TaskCompletionSource` to set the results.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, with a properly-implemented `async` method to call:

```
[OperationContract]
string ExecuteProgram(string clientId, string program, string[] args)
{
    Task<string> task = DbManager.DoRequestAsync(clientId, program, args);
    return task.Result;
}
```

Are you manually managing the 10 DB connections? It sounds like you've re-implemented database connection pooling. Perhaps you should be using the connection pooling built-in to your DB server or driver.

Comment: Yes it should work but what would be the advantage over calling directly `return DbManager.DoRequest(....)`

Comment: If the implementation of ExecuteProgram does not follow the async pattern itself, that thread will not be able to process multiple requests.

Comment: We actually are trying to implement connection pooling (kinda). The database we are using is not your run-of-the-mill sql/nosql database unfortunately.

Comment: @Clamidity then all the bla bla in your question is unnecessary since connection pooling can be used in any code, not only in WCF. Write your code and use in all environments....

Comment: Our db server/driver does not have built-in connection pooling. That is why we are trying to implement it on our own. We connect to the database through telnet/ssh.

Comment: @I4V True, I simply wanted to lay out what had already been done/the environment I was working with. I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single database server (which I suspect is likely), then just use a `BlockingCollection` for your pool.